# Pulling specific data from Firebase and Java

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire

I am attempting to pull a specific data element from a list in Firebase. How can i set a variable to the data for a specific element that way i can use it for another function?

```
  getProducts() {
    return this.angularfire.database.list('/products', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'name'
      }
    });
  }

this.loadingProvider.show();
// Get all products from database.
this.dataProvider.getProducts().subscribe((products) => {
  this.products = products;

  console.log (products);
  this.products.forEach((product) => {
    // Add observer for the owner of the product to detect changes.
    this.dataProvider.getUser(product.userId).subscribe((user) => {
      product.user = user;
    });
```

[Screenshot of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMI0S.png)

Comment: So what's your question? :) What's the current behavior and what's the expected behavior? what variable do you want to populate? and use it where?

Comment: The current behavior - grabs all product information for a list of objects. Each product contains a key and under the key there are several data elements. How do i grab a specific data element within the objects in a list, that way i grab all of that specific data element within each object. There is a data element called type in each product objects. If i wanted to grab that data element for each product and set it to a private variable, how would i do this?

Comment: It would be much easier to follow if you could add a snippet of your data and then show us what result you want. It would be much easier to follow, now my head starts spinning to try and understand how your data looks like from only text :)

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the data. I want to pull all the ASINs

Comment: Okay, where do you want to assign the asins? A New array? if so, an array of objects or array of string?

Comment: yes, i want grab on the ASINs from the objects in an array associated to the variable i can place into a function.

Comment: An array of string.

Comment: I am trying to place the ASINs into this function in the ItemId from an string array.

Comment: uhmm... okay, well then you can discard my current answer. So you do not want a new array. I'm confused again :D

Comment: Ok, so i want to pull all the ASINs from each object and push them into the ItemId: as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from comments... and if I understood correctly...

If you want an object array from your asins in your products array, you can do this:

```
asins: string[] = [];
```

and iterate your products and pull the asins from there:

```
this.products.forEach(product => {
   this.asins.push(product.ASIN)
});
```

With that you end up with a string array containing your asins:

```
["ASIN1", "ASIN2", "ASIN3"]
```

Comment: If it is really that easy i am going to kick myself. lol. I am trying it now.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Question, how do i get my array ["B0009YWKUA", "B003YMAHOA"] to be 'B0009YWKUA', 'B003YMAHOA'

Comment: I figured it out. i just needed to add .string() to this.asins

Comment: Okay greaaaat that you figured it out :) Since this solved your issue, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey tick that is under the voting of this answer :) Have a great weekend and happy coding! :)

Comment: question: when i do a console.log(product.asin.string()) it will the first element and print it out and then it will pull the first and the second element as a print out. How do i just pull the entire array only?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, could you try and explain in another way. Where are you printing this, in the foreach or where? And what do you mean by "pull entire array only" :)

Comment: I'm just checking my results in a console.log using google development console. When my array print, it will print this B0009YWKUA and then it will print B0009YWKUA,B003YMAHOA; all i want is to show all the values on one output only or on one line.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can do e.g `console.log(this.asins.toString())` Is that what you wish?

Comment: That is what i am using right now and it returns B0009YWKUA
products.ts:146 B0009YWKUA,B003YMAHOA products.ts:146 ; So it is returning two different entries; is there a way for me to return only the last record and not the first one? So it just displays B0009YWKUA,B003YMAHOA products.ts:146 and that is it?

Comment: So you want the last item in the array? Check this one, it logs "three",which is the last record. https://plnkr.co/edit/NxYTIP4eDsDFWzTEQVoE?p=preview

Comment: I actually just want the entire array on one line.

Comment: Well, that is what exactly `this.asins.toString()` does. In my plunker it prints `one,two,three`.Updated the plunker.

Comment: I see that now. Thanks for helping me with this.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)